# SwiftUI Picker - Options won't show

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

Ive been trying to implement a picker for an app but for some reason the options won't pop up. any help would be appreciated!

'''

```
let strengths = ["Host", "Snacks", "Drinks"]

@State private var viewModel = User.userList

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{

                Section(header: Text("Roles")) {
                    
                    
                    ForEach(User.userList) { user in
                        
                        Picker(user.name, selection: $selectedStrength){
                            
                            ForEach(strengths, id: \.self) { strength in
                                     Text(strength)
                                }
                           
                        }
                        // picker
                     }.padding()
        
                }

 }
```

'''

[image: The options won't show]

Comment: What happens when you click on the arrows next to the names? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Is there a `NavigationView` somewhere in a parent view? Or is this in Preview and you didn't wrap it in a `NavigationView` in your `PreviewProvider`? Otherwise, provide a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: you only have 1 `$selectedStrength` for all your users. This is not correct. Note, you should probably use `ForEach(viewModel) { user in ...}`
  instead of `ForEach(User.userList) { user in ...}`. And of course provide a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: When I click on the arrows, nothing appears.

Comment: How do I make a selectedStrength for all my users.

Comment: Also, im new to stack so im not sure what minimal reproducible example is

Comment: "...not sure what minimal reproducible example is..", you mean you did not read the link lorem ipsum posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...How do I make a selectedStrength for all my users..",
you could add the `var strength: String` in your `User` struct and use that in your `Picker` , such as in this example code:

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var strength: String  // <-- here
    // ...
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let strengths = ["Host", "Snacks", "Drinks"]
    @State private var viewModel = [User(name: "user1", strength: ""),
                                    User(name: "user2", strength: ""),
                                    User(name: "user3", strength: "")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {  // <-- here
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Roles")) {
                    ForEach($viewModel) { $user in
                        Picker(user.name, selection: $user.strength){
                            ForEach(strengths, id: \.self) { strength in
                                Text(strength)
                            }
                        }
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use this:

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Roles")) {
            ForEach($viewModel) { $user in
                HStack {
                    Text(user.name)
                    Spacer()
                    Picker("", selection: $user.strength){
                        ForEach(strengths, id: \.self) { strength in
                            Text(strength)
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(.menu)
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said but it just displays the picker segmentedly without showing the name of the person. I want it to be a menu like clicker

Comment: updated my answer with `a menu like clicker`.